# Remove N/A option in radio button

Tags: 8, forms

I made a field in text list format with radio button widget and I want to remove the N/A option, but my field must be not required.

I tried this code without success.

```php
function mymodule_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['radios'])) {
    $types['radios']['#process'][] = 'remove_radio_na';
  }
}

function remove_radio_na($element) {
  if ($element['#field_name']=='field_align_image') {
    unset($element['_none']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Do you have an idea on how I can solve my issue?

Comment: What does “without success” mean?

Comment: If you remove the "N/A" option and the user clicks a radio button (thereby setting it by mistake), it will be impossible for that user to deselect the radio button, effectively making the radio button required (if the user makes a mistake).  This is horrible usability.

Comment: I usually work around this scenario by using a `<select>` element instead.